# Porting SWFs to Android devices

Tags: android, flash, mobile, actionscript-2

we have a number of **SWFs** we want to repurpose as Android apps, but are having trouble finding some information.

I realise that Android is spread across a lot of different Hardware but are there any standardised resolutions? If not how would you go about resizing the Stage depending on the screen?

Secondly can **SWFs** be uploaded to the Android store and if not what is the best way to mantain the **SWF** functionality whilst converting it to a format that can?

Any other advice you think important would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the Android docs (with some representative screen sizes at the foot of the page): http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

First of all, in order to deploy your app to the Android store you need to publish it as an AIR file. (Note that this needs the Android device to have AIR on it: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.adobe.air).

You can get the screen resolution for the app using the `flash.system.capabilities`:

```
trace(Capabilities.screenResolutionX);
trace(Capabilities.screenResolutionY);
```

or  via `flash.display.screen` when using AIR as this contains additional screen information.

Finally you also need to bear in mind the screen orientation (see http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/screen_orientation_apis.html). You may want to consider multi-touch as well, and review you app from the UI point of view to take on board the different user experience of Android compared with the web.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try GAF Converter. it is goood solution for porting swf files to Android. it supports numerous features and I think it will help you.